# Doctrine DBAL 2.11 and TYPO3 extbase sorting creates empty where conditions

Tags: sql, doctrine, typo3, extbase

Using in your TYPO3 v9.5.21 Extbase repository sth. like

```
protected $defaultOrderings = [
    'child.sorting' => \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Persistence\QueryInterface::ORDER_ASCENDING
];
```

creates an empty statement in your WHERE clause with doctrine/dbal 2.11.

```
WHERE () AND (....
```

With doctrine/dbal 2.10. is everything ok.

Don't know if it is an issue with TYPO3 or doctrine.

Answer (score 0):

Could be related to this ticket https://github.com/doctrine/dbal/issues/4282